# Lock word document for forms but have open for markups

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm very familiar with using word documents as locked for forms but I have used "section breaks" to create areas where the user can free type. I'm trying to find a way to have another user of the form, mark up with comments in the free type areas without unlocking the document as its password protected. Any ideas on how I might achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Using the same editing restriction (Filling in Forms) you can assign different sections to be freely editable or locked. This is controlled via the `Settings` hyperlink under Editing Restrictions.